# Axios GET - corrupt data downloading raw binary zip

Tags: node.js, express, encoding, axios, zip

#### Issue description

I have an endpoint which returns binary raw zip data. When I consume this endpoint via Postman and "Save to file", the downloaded zip file gets extracted just fine no issues. If I hit the endpoint on browser as well it downloads the zip & extracts with no issues. So, there is no issue with the binary raw data itself.

BUT when I try to download via Axios, I get below error while extracting the zip file. After a lot of digging, I've narrowed it down to some bytes being missing (Corrupted zip: missing 26 bytes) for some reason which points to me not using the right Axios config to properly transform, encode the binary data.

I've been trying all possible config changes (responseType as `stream/arraybuffer/blob`, responseEncoding as `null/utf8/binary` etc) still doesn't seem to fix the corrupt file!

#### Error

Whenever I try to unzip the file, I get the error:

> Unable to expand "test.zip" (Error 79 - Inappropriate file type of format)

If I set the header with Content-Length, then I get this error while unzipping:

> Unable to expand "test.zip" (Error 1 - No such process)

PS: I have another endpoint which returns raw binary PDF data and Axios downloads that perfectly fine! Its just an issue with raw binary ZIP data by the looks of it.

#### Code

```js
// handling the axios request
getZipFile: ({}) => Axios.get('/zipfile, { params: {...} }, {
  responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  responseEncoding: null,
  maxContentLength: 20000,
  transformResponse: data => data,
})

// handling the axios response
const { data, headers = {} } = await getZipFile({})
console.log(data) // returns corrupted raw binary zip data

res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="test.zip"');
return res.end(data);
```

#### Versions

- Axios 1.3.5
- Node 17.9.0
- Express 4.18.2

Comment: Do not attempt to print binary data, and definitely don't put such attempts in your question. Such output is completely useless, as it is not a faithful representation. All those white-on-black-hexagon question marks are lost data. Either provide links to the files, or encode them in the question as hexadecimal or Base-64.

Comment: @MarkAdler - you're right. I just wanted to show that the Axios seems to corrupt the response when browser/postman could download it - will remove the binary text from question. Also regarding lost data, white-on-black-hexagon are present on the binary data which worked as well so its not that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. Posting the answer here just in case others are facing the same problem.

`Axios.get` apparently only takes 2 arguments (`url` and `config`). Since `Axios.post` takes in 3 arguments (`url`, `data` and `config`) - I was under the impression GET would be the same but I was mistaken.

So the correct version of the above code is:

```js
// handling the axios request
getZipFile: ({}) => Axios.get('/zipfile, {
  params: {...},
  responseType: 'arraybuffer'
})
```

Basically, `params` and `responseType` is at the same level within the config. The other configs like `responseEncoding` etc were not needed.